# Warnings of changes made by installers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to ensure that when I install a program, I can be prompted of any network changes made? I know that some sysinternals tools and other tools can tell me what changes an installer makes, but I'd like warnings.

Thanks

Comment: What's a 'network change'?

Answer (score 3):

No, not without disassembling every installer you get.